# Set up Redis on Windows Azure VM (Windows) and make it reachable to outher VMs under the same cloud service

Tags: azure, redis, windows-server-2008-r2, azure-virtual-machine

Here is my scenario:

I have three Windows VMs on Windows Azure (which is at its preview stage right now) and all the VMs are connected to each other, in other words they are under the same cloud service. What I need to do now is that I will use one VM only for Redis and the other two VMs need to talk to it. I don't wanna open up the redis to the whole World for several reasons and one of them is that I don't want to talk to it through the load balancer. I want my VMs to talk to it directly (as explained here: [Bypass the load balancer when communicating servers between each other](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/9a1afea2-774c-464c-be8b-986abcba9def)).

I consider using [MSOpenTech implementation of Redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis). Any I idea how I can configure a structure like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by trying it out. Here is the solution:

[SignalR with Redis Running on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/singalr-with-redis-running-on-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Running Redis on A Windows Azure Virtual Machine (Windows or Linux) is exactly same as any other machine so I don't think you will met any problem there.

If you have one instance of Virtual Machine it is not configured through Load Balancer and you can see that when you will add endpoint to your VM. Only if you have more then 1 instances of a virtual machine, and then you add endpoint, then you will have a chance to configure the load blanacer for that specific endpoint. In your case as you want to run Redis on one single VM, you are really not behind load balancer.

IF you want to have your all 3 machines talking to each other you can create a virtual network and provision all 3 machines withing this VNET so they can talk to each other the way you want.

Comment: I assumed that everything which goes through VIP is having the cost of LB, isn't it? Actually, I managed to get it working and I am connecting the redis through VM name as shown in this picture (https://p.twimg.com/Awy__AvCIAE-hLu.png:large). I will provide a detailed answer when I have time.

Comment: VIP along with multiple virtual machines go through LB.

Comment: thanks! so, communicating through internal endpoint would be a wise decision here I guess. There is also a long domain name I see when I ping my other vm from another vm (ping SLRedis-08R2). Do you know that this name is something persistent? I mean, is it going to change when my vm is reprovisioned if a hardware failure accours?  can I rely on that?